# How to check at what times the table in SQL Server was updated

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server (table name -> city)

I want to check at what times the table (city) was updated, I need its modifications time of yesterday (i.e. that at what exact times the table was updated, such that if the table (city) was updated at 2:00 PM, 3:00 PM, 5:30 PM, etc, then I want all the data and not just its last modification time.

I have used the below SQL query but it gave me blank result:-

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS `DatabaseName`, last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'AdventureWorks')
AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('city')
```

Comment: `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` will only have a single record per object, each with the datetime of the most recent update in the `last_user_update` field, so you cannot use it to get the kind of history you are looking for as far as I know, just to see when it was last updated.

Comment: Have you enabled audit for that table?

Comment: As for the actual issue with your query returning no results, have you confirmed that the table `city` definitely exists in the `AdventureWorks` database? Try running `SELECT object_id FROM sys.objects WHERE name = 'city'` on the `Adventureworks` database itself and confirm the value you get (if any) is the same as running `SELECT OBJECT_ID('city')`. If the values don't match - or more likely the first query returns nothing - that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much it gonna help you.

```
SELECT    [TableName] = name,
create_date,
modify_date
FROM    sys.tables
WHERE    name = 'your_Table_Name'
```

another way

```
SELECT    [TableName] = OBJECT_NAME(object_id),
last_user_update, last_user_seek, last_user_scan, last_user_lookup
FROM    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE  OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'Your_Table_Name'
```

N.B:please see the [***Source Site***](https://sqlandme.com/2014/03/11/sql-server-how-to-get-last-accessupdate-time-for-a-table/) for more clearification.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have enabled Audit,it is not possible to do what you are asking(getting all data ,not only last one)

few options i could think off..

**1.Query Tlog:**
run this on backup of database and not current one,since this is very resource intensive..

```
select operation,allocunitname,[begin time],[transaction name]
 from
fn_dblog(null,null)
where [transaction id] in
(
select  [transaction id]
from
fn_dblog(null,null) where operation='LOP_MODIFY_ROW' and 
allocunitname not like 'sys.%' and allocunitname not like '%unknown%' 
)
```

**Output:**

```
operation      allocunitname    begin time              transaction name
LOP_BEGIN_XACT  NULL           2016/12/22 16:37:23:107  FirstPage Alloc
LOP_MODIFY_ROW  dbo.t1          NULL                    NULL
LOP_MODIFY_ROW  dbo.t1           NULL                   NULL
LOP_COMMIT_XACT NULL              NULL                   NULL
LOP_BEGIN_XACT  NULL          2016/12/22 16:37:33:860   UPDATE
LOP_MODIFY_ROW  dbo.t1             NULL                 NULL
LOP_COMMIT_XACT NULL               NULL                 NULL
```

**option 2:**
1.Enable Audit if you want for all tables..if this is for a single table ,use history tables

**Option 3:**
If on SQL2016,you can use Temporal tables